# Resume AVAudioplayer after interruption ends

Tags: iphone

Having issue when interruption like phone call comes it pauses audio but when interruption ends app is not resuming audioplayer. Please suggest how i can resume the audio player back

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by replaying the last playing item. That means you should reinstanciate your AVPlayerItem. If you did find a better solution please keep me in touch as soon as possible. Thanks.